# I need refresh page to see result api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with mounting a component in react.js

I have API call to backend endpoint:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 const getOrders = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await userRequest.get(
      "orders/find/63c18620cf0c78c4a0cf7ff9"
    );
    const data = await res.data;
    setOrders(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
 getOrders();
}, []);
```

Component

```
{orders.map((item) => {
    return (
     <ProductContainer key={item._id}>
       <OrderProduct item={item} />
     </ProductContainer>
   );
})}
```

Request Method

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;

const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;

const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

When I load the page is always problem: "Request failed with status code 403", and ofc I don't see any data.

But when I refresh page, everything look good and I see all data.

Comment: Are you passing `headers`?

Comment: Can you show some details on `userRequest`?

Comment: you place request function in useEffect that make request work  twice quickly,so serve side tell you 403, dont make two requests in a very short time. dont init data in useEffect

Comment: It seems that `userRequest` is not having required authorization token during the 1st request.

Answer (score 0):

you should first check your data recive or no. then you can use map on it.
the second thought is, if you haven't loader, you can get the data without useEffect.
if your problem dosen't solve, you should check `userRequest`